# How to add a period of time to structure of ' in a such short time'

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to add a specific period of time to 'in a such short time'.
How to add a specific period into following the sentence?

For example :

> The company rose its profit from $100 million to 500 million between
>   in the years 2010 to 2015. The company have come a long way
>   tremendously in a such short time  + 5 years.

or

> The change in nature is incredible for a such short time + a specific period.

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is "...in **only** five years."

Comment: @stangdon I thought too. However, apparently it works for the first sentence but not the second sentence.

Comment: What's wrong with "The change in nature is incredible for only five years"?  It isn't the best-sounding sentence I can think of, but it isn't wrong, either.

Comment: @stangdon Your last sentence is okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me correct one or two minor errors in your example sentence:

> The company's profits rose from $100 million to $500 million between in the years 2010 to 2015. The company has come a tremendously long way in such a short time.

- **[rise](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rise)** is an intransitive verb: it doesn't take an object, so the company cannot **rise** its profits. The company can increase its profits, or the company's profits can rise.
- **[tremendously](http://tremendously)** is an adverb that qualifies the adjective **long**, and so it must precede the adjective.
- **[such](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/such)** is a predeterminer: the **pre** bit means that you place it before the determiner **a**.
- **the company** is singular, so it should be followed by **has**, not **have**.

To answer your question, you can add a specific time using the **such... as** construct:

> The company's profits rose from $100 million to $500 million between in the years 2010 to 2015. The company has come a tremendously long way in such a short time **as five years**.
>
> The change in nature is incredible for such a short time **as ten years**.

In both cases, it would sound more natural to replace **such a short time as** by **only**.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a specific period of time like this:

> The change in nature **across just three months** is incredible.
>
> The change in nature is incredible for **just three months**.

Both examples are acceptable, however, I personally would use the first one more, unless I added something like "three months of work" to the end of the second one.

For the second example, you could use this:

> The company has come a long way in **just 5 years**.

Comment: +1 "Just" is the key word here - when used with time it implies that it's short or surprisingly short or noticeably short.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can I use  "over" too instead of "across"  in your first sentence?

Comment: @Mrt Yes, "over" will also work.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how formal/informal your writing is meant to be, **'skyrocketed'** is a word often used to describe such a scenario.

> The company's profits **skyrocketed** from $100 million to 500 million
>   between 2010 and 2015

Much like a literal rocket, the term means to to shoot up rapidly, e.g. prices are skyrocketing.

Answer (score 2):

**Company profits soared** from $100 million to 500 million between 2010 and 2015. [this is typical finance-speak].

The company **grew its profits** from $100 million to 500 million between 2010 to 2015.

**The company has grown significantly** in just five years.

**change is nature is not used in company-speak**. They haven't "changed in nature". **The company has grown, expanded, seen incredible growth or experienced incredible growth in just five years.**

Comment: Thank you. Since  "finance -speak" is mentioned, I was wondering if  saying   " there is a raise (not rise) in its profits" or " there is a raise in the company's profits or procurements"   sounds wrong because the noun raise is used with word salary especially in AmE.

Comment: By the way, when I used "nature" in my question, I meant  "  Mother Nature"

Comment: Profits rose, profits soared, profits climbed. Are we in finance and business or nature? I really am missing something, I guess. No business writer would write: There is a rise in its profits: Profits rose dramatically from 2005 to 2010. Forget raise/rise as a noun for salaries. That is something different with no bearing here: He got a rise [British English]; He got a raise [American English]. Not the same context at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well in order to make clear the context in my question, I can say they are random sentences. At first,  I wrote down the first sentence but then I saw/noticed people can miss the point of the question by answering  " ... in  such a short time in five years" so I added another sentence as if I imagined there is a big change in nature like deforestation or forestation. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: @Mrt Ok, now I see. The two were not related. Got it. /in such a short time/; /in a few years/. The preposition is in. It is incredible for a change to have occurred in such a short time.